# Approximating $\pi$ with least digits

Tags: approximation, pi

Do you a digit efficient way to approximate $\pi$? I mean representing many digits of $\pi$ using only a few numeric digits and some sort of equation. Maybe mathematical operations also count as penalty.

For example the well known $\frac{355}{113}$ is an approximation, but it gives only 7 correct digits by using 6 digits (113355) in the approximation itself. Can you make a better *digit ratio*?

EDIT: to clarify the "game" let's assume that each mathematical operation (+, sqrt, power, ...) also counts as one digit. Otherwise one could of course make artifical infinitely nested structures of operations only. And preferably let's stick to basic arithmetics and powers/roots only.

EDIT: true. logarithm of imaginary numbers provides an easy way. let's not use complex numbers since that's what I had in mind. something you can present to non-mathematicians :)

Comment: Section 7.6 of [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_%CF%80#Miscellaneous_approximations) contains much of the information you desire.

Comment: @CliveNewstead: do you see a particularly efficient way in these equations which "saves digits"?

Comment: I can't help but mention that if you represent pi with a decimal, you achieve a 1:1 ratio. If you use a larger-than-10 base for this number, though, you can achieve a very good ratio. I think this method, if legal, would give you the best ratio among the non-exact methods. Unfortunately this method is also not very interesting.

Comment: You may be interested in http://math.stackexchange.com/a/147422/27624

Comment: @EricThoma: true, but not very efficient ;) Of course on other base system one would have to adjust for the larger digit variety by entropy means.

Comment: A few approximations: $$\begin{align*}\pi&\approx \sqrt[4]{\frac{2143}{22}}\\\pi&\approx \sqrt{\frac{99+\sqrt{9681}}{20}}\end{align*}$$

Comment: @JM: The power 4 one is interesting, but does not give more digits than it uses. Yesterday I rediscovered this when I checked all powers for continued fractions :) Neither does the second give much more digits than it uses :(

Comment: I just tried the common powerful series approximations, but they give a constant number of pi digits, while requiring a lot of digits per term :( So again no "compression" of pi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me throw in Clive's suggestion to look at the wikipedia site. If we allow for logarithm (while not using complex numbers), we can get 30 digits of $\pi$ with

$\frac{\operatorname{ln}(640320^3+744)}{\sqrt{163}}$

which is 13 digits and 5 operation, giving a ratio of about 18/30=0.6.

EDIT: Here is another one I found on this site:

$\ln(31.8\ln(2)+\ln(3))$

gives 11 digits of $\pi$ with using 5 numbers and 4 operations.

Answer (score 13):

Using continued fractions you may get as many ratios as you wish and all the ratios are as good as possible!) :

I'll steal part of what I wrote in this other [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175943/float-result-for-two-smallest-integer-division/175984#175984) and adapt it!

To use [continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for evaluation of $x=\pi$.

At each step :

- note the integer part $j\leftarrow \lfloor x\rfloor$ (illustrated in blue)
- compute the new fraction $f$ as illustrated :

  - write the previous fraction
  - multiply the numerator and denominator by $j$
  - add the numerator and denominator of the previous previous fraction (starting with $\frac 10$)
- evaluate the fractional part $x\leftarrow x-j$
- stop when $x$ becomes $0$ or at least very small (depending of the precision of your evaluation) or when you decide too...
- else compute $x$'s multiplicative inverse $x\leftarrow \frac 1x$ and repeat

$
\begin{array} {l|r|ccccc}
x&j&&&&&f\\
\hline\\
3.141592653589\cdots & \color{#0000ff}{3} & \color{#0000ff}{3}&=&\frac {\color{#0000ff}{3}}1&=&\frac 31\\
1/0.141592\cdots=7.0625\cdots & \color{#0000ff}{7} &3+\cfrac 1{\color{#0000ff}{7}}&=& \frac {3\cdot \color{#0000ff}{7}+1}{1\cdot \color{#0000ff}{7} +0}&=&\frac {22}{7}\\
1/7.0625\cdots=15.99659\cdots & \color{#0000ff}{15}&3+\cfrac 1{7+\cfrac 1{\color{#0000ff}{15}}}&=& \frac {22\cdot \color{#0000ff}{15}+3}{7\cdot \color{#0000ff}{15} +1}&=&\frac {333}{106}\\
1/0.99659\cdots=1.0034172\cdots & \color{#0000ff}{1}&3+\cfrac 1{7+\cfrac 1{15+\cfrac 1{\color{#0000ff}{1}}}}&=& \frac {333\cdot \color{#0000ff}{1}+22}{106\cdot \color{#0000ff}{1} +7}&=&\frac {355}{113}\\
\cdots &\\
1/0.003417231\cdots=292.63459\cdots & \color{#0000ff}{292}&3+\cfrac 1{7+\cfrac 1{15+\cfrac 1{1+\cfrac 1{\color{#0000ff}{292}}}}}&=& \frac {355\cdot \color{#0000ff}{292}+333}{113\cdot \color{#0000ff}{292} +106}&=&\frac {103993}{33102}\\
\cdots &\\
\end{array}
$

without end since $\pi$ is transcendental!

Comment: However, unless you get an enormous continuant fairly early, your digit ratio will still be close to $1$.

Comment: @robjohn: yes of course but the best quotients will be in this list (like $355/113$ because the next integer $j$ is large). I merely produced the best ones I was not doing miracles ;-)

Comment: As far as rational approximations go, you won't get better than continued fractions (if $|p-q\pi|<\frac1{2q}$, then $p/q$ comes from a continued fraction). I was just noting that the OP was considering digit ratios as important and, in general, continued fractions give a digit ratio of about $1$.

Comment: Anyway I think that $355/113$ is the best result (the next large continuant $20776$ is too far to count...) so that  'extended' rules should be used instead of fractions...

Comment: @robjohn: yes I agree (as you see from my previous comment). In fact I was editing (and answering elsewhere) while the rules changed...

Comment: What a latex magic!

Comment: Thanks @peterh even if the new SE 'formatting' made this somewhat ugly!  Another graphical LaTex attempt was this [$p_k(m)$ table](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1784987/21783) but the rendering time was too long. I am not at all an expert but enjoy to try the few graphical options available... Excellent experiments!

Answer (score 9):

With pure rational approximations, there are sharp limits (related to Roth's Theorem) in terms of how far you can go.

More generally, this will depend strongly on the operations allowed. For example,
$$
\log(0-1)/\sqrt{0-1}
$$
has 5 operations and 4 digits and is exact.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you can use the [Gauss Legendre Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm) ?
With 25 iterations, you will produce more than 45 million digits

For example, use bc with the desire scale, and do the algorithm. For a scale of 50, you obtain :

$$\pi_0=\color{red}{2.91421356237309504880168872420969807856967187537693}$$
$$\pi_1=3.14\color{red}{057925052216824831133126897582331177344023751285}$$
$$\pi_2=3.1415926\color{red}{4621354228214934443198269577431443722334535}$$
$$\pi_3=3.141592653589793238\color{red}{27951277480186397438122550483492}$$
$$\pi_4=3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971\color{red}{1467828263}$$
$$\pi_5=3.14159265358979323846264338327950288419716939937\color{red}{240}$$

(the last 3 digits of error don't come from the algorithm but from the limited scale)

For a scale of 1000, you obtain :

$\pi_9=$3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679821480865132823066470938446095505822317253594081284811174502841027019385211055596446229489549303819644288109756659334461284756482337867831652712019091456485669234603486104543266482133936072602491412737245870066063155881748815209209628292540917153643678925903600113305305488204665213841469519415116094330572703657595919530921861173819326117931051185480744623799627495673518857527248912279381830119491298336733624406566430860213949463952247371907021798609437027705392171762931767523846748184676694051320005681271452635608277857713427577896091736371787214684409012249534301465495853710507922796892589235420199561121290219608640344181598136297747713099605187072113499999983729780499510597317328160963185950244594553469083026425223082533446850352619311881710100031378387528865875332083814206171776691473035982534904287554687311595628638823537875937519577818577805321712268066130019278766111959092164$\color{red}{199382}$

So you work on a fixed scale and stop when the algorithm is almost on a fixed point. Only the (very) few last digits will be wrong. And you only need $\log(n)$ iterations for a scale of $n$ ($n$ digits).

Comment: is it efficient? or will it give an exponential explosion of operations, too?

Comment: You can efficiently use this algorithm, with pseudo linear size memory and operations. Of course $k.n\log(n)$ when $n$ is 45'000'000 can be a little too much for the memory part. But it's a very nice algorithm anyway..

Comment: Sure it's efficient. But if you write out the full equation you will get a very long expression which again isn't efficient anymore?

Comment: you can't expect an "algorithmic" expression shorter than the result. But if you stick to square root, multiplication and addition, this method will gives you the shortest for sure. Of course computing arithmetic on very large precision takes a lot of computing steps...

Comment: Can you write out a specific example? I believe with every steps the expression size grows exponentially.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Algorithmically this surely wins :) Yet, what if you try to expand all steps and write out one closed-form mathematical expression (no algorithmic notation allowed)? Will you end up with a deeply nested structure with many terms?

Comment: Deeeply nested for sure, as you do geometric mean and arithmetic mean each step.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a site that focuses on numerical computation of rational approximations of $\pi$:
http://www.isi.edu/~johnh/BLOG/1999/0728_RATIONAL_PI/

Also, using a truncated form of the [continued fraction](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiContinuedFraction.html) will give nice approximations.  The first few fractions given are $3$, $22\over7$, $333\over106$, $355\over113$, $103993 \over33102$ and $104348\over33215$.  These numerators and denominators are given by the [OEIS](http://oeis.org) sequences [A002485](http://oeis.org/A002485) and [A002486](http://oeis.org/A002486) respectively.

You may be interested in [this page](http://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10004.5.shtml).  It states that $355 \over 113$ is the "best" (efficiency-wise) rational approximation with the denominator less then 30,000.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I'm not the first to ask ->
http://www.contestcen.com/pi.htm

However, they often don't count operations. Surely, but defining the set of allow operations (+, -, *, /, sqrt, pow, ...?) one could set up an information "entropy" measure to make it a fair game :)

Answer (score 0):

(2143/22)^(1/4) = 3.14159265258

ignoring the parentheses & "^" since they don't get written when written with indices and grouping that's 9 digits/operations to get 9 digits. so 1:1 but I was happy I found it nonetheless

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).