# Rational approximation of pi

Tags: approximation, pi

I found this problem intriguing: $355 / 113 = 3.14159292035398\ldots$ gives the approximation of $\pi$ in $7$ correct numbers, say $C(355/113)=7$, but it number of digits in numerator + number of digits in denominator is six, say $L(355/113)=6$. How many rationals $a/b$ there are such that $L(a/b)<C(a/b)$?

Comment: The best rational approximations for a number are drawn from its [continued fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) expression.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180073/approximating-pi-with-least-digits?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a few OEIS sequences which may help answer this question:

A002485 https://oeis.org/A002485
A002486 https://oeis.org/A002486

I hope this helps.