# Approximations of $\pi$ using radicals

Tags: approximation, radicals, pi

There are many approximations of $\pi$ using trigonometric and rational numbers. But I created this one: $$\pi \approx \sqrt[11]{294204}$$ Which is correct to almost $8$ decimal places. Are there any other approximations of $\pi$ using radicals? I know of $\sqrt{10}$, $\sqrt[3]{31}$, $\sqrt[4]{97}$, and so on. But are there more beautiful ways (like using $\varphi$ since it is composed of radicals)?

Comment: [$\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/701822/409)

Comment: There are a few formulas for $\pi$ in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_radical#Nested_Square_Roots_of_2) which may be truncated to produce okayish approximations.

Comment: See also Wikipedia's ["Approximations of $\pi$" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximations_of_π).

Comment: Correct upto 7 places only but +1 vote.

Comment: This [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432729) appears relevant too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing your game, let me define
$$A_n=\text{Round}\left[\pi ^{p_n}\right]$$ and compute
$$\Delta_n=\log_{10}\Bigg[\left| A^{\frac{1}{p_n}}-\pi   \right| \Bigg]$$ where $p_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ prime number
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & A_n & \Delta_n\\
 5 & 294204 & -7.758 \\
 6 & 2903677 & -7.647 \\
 7 & 282844564 & -9.568 \\
 8 & 2791563950 & -10.62 \\
 9 & 271923706894 & -12.71 \\
 10 & 261424513284461 & -16.27 \\
 11 & 2580156526864959 & -16.72 \\
 12 & 2480534602660760780 & -19.83 \\
 13 & 241626620923575111130 & -22.04 \\
 14 & 2384759161287667022585 & -23.76 \\
 15 & 232297222236041657886386 & -25.24 \\
 16 & 223328039155291367651964249 & -28.00 \\
 17 & 214705163466259581466085919504 & -32.68 \\
 18 & 2119055026283205737110078195749 & -31.92 \\
 19 & 2037236602860106711985144771884927 & -35.04 \\
 20 & 198445365705802004702001456166116206 & -37.30 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ showing that, more or less, $\Delta_n=6.156-2.190\,n$

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of radical approximations to $\pi$. A classical example is given by [Viete's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vi%C3%A8te%27s_formula), in which a series of increasingly complicated nested radicals may be used to render $2/\pi$:

$2/\pi=\Pi_{n=1}^\infty(a_n/2)$

$a_1=\sqrt2, a_n=\sqrt{2+a_{n-1}}.$

Many readers are aware that this series is derived by considering the perimeters of inscribed regular polygons having $2^k$ sides, these approaching the circumference of a circle as $k\to\infty$.

Just for fun, let's explore a method based on the Taylor series for the cosine function. Pick a value of $n$ for which $\cos(\pi/n)$ has a convenient radical expression and plug in the Taylor series approximation

$\cos(\pi/n)\approx 1-[(\pi/n)^2/2]+[(\pi/n)^4/24].$

Then substitute the radical expression for $\cos(\pi/n)$ on the left and solve the biquadratic polynomial by standard methods for "$\pi/n$".

With $n=5,\cos(\pi/5)=(\sqrt5+1)/4$ this gives

$\pi\approx5\sqrt{6-\sqrt3×(\sqrt5+1)}=\color{blue}{3.142}3...$

(correct to the significant digits indicated in blue.)

Answer (score 2):

COMMENT: By way of simple pertinent information.

There are many remarkable approximations of $\pi$. For example
$$\pi\approx\dfrac{22}{17}+\dfrac{37}{47}+\dfrac{88}{43}\\\pi\approx\sqrt[4]{\frac{2143}{22}}\\\pi\approx\sqrt[9]{\frac{34041350274878}{1141978491}}\\\pi\approx\frac{\ln(640320^3+744)}{\sqrt{163}} $$
The first and second each give $9$ exact decimal places, the third gives $15$ and the fourth gives $30$.

**Buffon's experiment**.- On any flat surface covered by parallel straight bands of equal width, a rod of length equal to the width of the bands is pulled a given number $T$ of times. In each shot the rod either stays within a band or cuts one of the parallel delimiting lines. Let $C$ be the number of cuts obtained; the quotient $\dfrac{2T}{c}$ it will be in principle the closer to $\pi$ the higher the number $T$.

In 1901, the Italian M. Lazzarini using a rod with a length equal to $\dfrac56$ of the width of the bands (in which case the theoretical probability of cutting is $\dfrac{5\pi}{3}$, he got in 3408 shots the rational approximation $\dfrac{355}{113}\approx3.141592$ .

Answer (score 2):

The well-known $\pi \approx \frac{\ln\left(5280^3\,+\,744\right)}{\sqrt{67}}$ and $\pi \approx \frac{\ln\left(640320^3\,+\,744\right)}{\sqrt{163}}$ involves the *j-function* and integers. But we can also use the *Dedekind eta function* and radicals,
$$\begin{align}
\pi &\approx \frac{\ln\left(2^6\phi^6-24\right)}{\sqrt{5}}\\
\pi &\approx \frac{\ln\left(2^6\phi^{12}+24\right)}{\sqrt{10}}\\
\pi &\approx \frac{\ln\left(2^{12}\phi^8-24\right)}{\sqrt{15}}\\
\pi &\approx \frac{\ln\left(2^6\phi^{24}-24\right)}{\sqrt{25}}
\end{align}$$
with golden ratio $\phi =\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$. The last two are correct to $9$ and $12$ decimal places, respectively.

**P.S.** The consistent appearance of $24$, the powers that are factors of $24$, and the radicands that are multiples of $5$ are clues the above are ***not*** coincidences and in fact have a mathematical reason behind them. Lovely, aren't they?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the Taylor series method given by https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4572788/945129

$\cos(x)+\cos(xe^{2\pi i/3})+\cos(xe^{4\pi i/3})=3 - x^6/240 + x^{12}/159667200 ...$

this is also equal to: $\cos(x) + 2 \cos(x/2) \cosh((x\sqrt 3)/2)$

setting $x= \pi$ removes the hyperbolic parts

we have $\pi/2 \approx\sqrt[6]{15}$ which differs from the claim by $3.7   \times 10^{-4}$

Related ones:

and  $\pi/2 \approx\sqrt[12]{\frac{77}{691}} \sqrt[6]{45} $ which differs from the claim by $2.47   \times 10^{-7}$

and $\pi/2 \approx\sqrt[8]{\frac{70}{17}} \sqrt[4]{3} $ which differs from the claim by $3   \times 10^{-5}$